# In SSRS how to conditionally change the colour of a datalabel font on a chart when it appears on the bar

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, bar-chart

I have created a bar chart that shows values on data labels.

The Data label is placed outside the bar

[image]

But in some cases the label appears on the bar where the bar is too long.

[image]

In this scenario I would like to conditionally change the font/colour  of the data label so that it's more visible.

However I can't see a way to  dynamically determine where the label has been placed.

Answer (score 1):

What I can think of is this. You can change the background/font color of all those series labels who's value lies in the range of 95%-100% of the maximum "Value". To be exactly precise as to what should be the threshold to change the bg/font color seems a daunting task, but you could play around with test data.

For writing the expression to change the font color,I would first change the dataset and add a column on the lines of *PercOfMax*. This column can be calculated easily in the dataset by using basic aggregate functions. 
Then you need to go to the `Chart Series Label properties-->Color` and write the expression on the lines of -

```
=IIF(Fields!PercOfMax.Value>=95, "YELLOW", "BLACK")
```

As I said, you might need to do some more research to finalize the value of this threshold(which I am assuming to be 95).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this problem is to use fill colour of the label and set its background to a bright colour (e.g. colour), and leave the font colour of the label black. Thus you can always see the label, and there is no difference when it's outside of the bar.